# Name-based VirtualHosts by subfolder

Tags: apache, apache2, virtualhost

I'm trying to configure Apache with three different VirtualHosts, such that a specific VirtualHost will be used when someone requests either the corresponding subdomain (e.g. `foo.example.com`) or the corresponding subfolder (e.g. `example.com/foo`).

I thought the following `httpd.conf` would do the trick, but the `ServerAlias` directives are simply being ignored:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/http
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName foo.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com/foo
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/web
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName bar.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com/bar
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

When `bar.example.com` is requested the third VirtualHost is used, as intended. However, in the case of `example.com/bar` the first VirtualHost takes precedence despite the `ServerAlias`. Similarly, requesting `example.com/foo` matches the first VirtualHost, not the second.

How can I fix this configuration to produce the desired behavior?

Comment: ServerAlias is an alternative name for a website. It was not designed to assign sub domains with sub-directories. Please see the documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias

Comment: @falconspy The documentation has [an example](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html#using) with ServerAlias serving as an alternative ServerName, and states that it "sets the alternate names for a host, for use with name-based virtual hosts." That makes it sound pretty interchangeable with ServerName.

Answer (score 0):

ServerAlias takes a hostname, not a hostname and a path.  This mechanism doesn't do what you want it to do. Just create an Alias or Redirect in the virtual *host* being accessed.